# php shell_exec not working with puppeteer

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

- Web server: nginx
- PHP framework: Laravel 5.5
- Library to generate PDF: [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

So what I want to do is, when user click on the **Download** button, then the server will do the following:

1. Construct a HTML file with content
2. run the following code

Laravel controller

```
$shell_output = shell_exec('`which node` ' . base_path('bin/export.js') . ' ' . $html_file . ' ' . $pdf_file . ' A4');
print($shell_output); // <------- empty output

$workable_output = shell_exec('echo `which node`');
print($shell_output); // <------- THIS IS SHOWING "/usr/local/bin/node"
```

the **export.js** content

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var filename = process.argv[2];
var output = process.argv[3];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 1415 });
  await page.goto('file://' + filename, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await page.emulateMedia('print');
  await page.pdf({
    path: output,
    format: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    landscape: false,
    margin: {
      top: '60px',
      right: '20px',
      bottom: '30px',
      left: '20px'
    }
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

But the problem is, no PDF file is generated, and the `$shell_output` also empty.

Then I try the run the shell command in terminal, and it works perfectly. i.e.

```
$ `which node` export.js content.html content.pdf A4
```

Again, I've tried to create a php file, and run with php-cli, i.e.

```
$ php test.php
```

the content of **test.php** as below

```
<?php
$shell_output = shell_exec('env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" `which node` export.js content.html content.pdf A4');
echo $shell_output;
```

### Server log

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
2018/03/13 10:37:05 [error] 13017#13017: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53
```

***P/S: I'm hosted in AWS EC2. This has no problem when I run in local machine.***

### Update on 2018-03-14 14:55PM (UTC+8)

I tried to put the code to tests folder in Laravel

**./tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php**

```
$shell_output = shell_exec('`which node` ' . base_path('bin/export.js') . ' ' . $html_file . ' ' . $pdf_file . ' A4');
```

And run with *ubuntu* user, it works

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/project$ ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --filter ExampleTest
PHPUnit 6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.
.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 4.82 seconds, Memory: 14.00MB
```

BUT, when I try to run with *www-data* user, it failed

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/project$ sudo -u www-data ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --filter ExampleTest
PHPUnit 6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.(node:7991) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:330:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:500:9)
    at Function.launch (/var/www/project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:106:40)
    at <anonymous>
(node:7991) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7991) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 276 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

Any idea where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, it's caused by the `chrome` executable itself

Solved by

```
$ chmod 777 /var/www/project/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-536395/chrome-linux/*
```

Found this from [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1999).